# Adjoints and scalar product.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, $\dim(V)=n<\infty$, $\psi$ a scalar product on $V$ which is not degenerate. Let $f \in \text{End}(V)$, $W \subset V $ such that $f(W) \subset W$. Denote with $f^*$ the adjoint of $f$.

After proving that $W^{\perp}$ is $f^*$-invariant, which means $f^*(W^{\perp})\subset W^{\perp}$ I'm asked to prove that::

> The characteristic polynomial of $f^*|_{W^{\perp}}$ divides the characteristic polynomial of $f$.

I really don't know how to proceed and I'd like to receive a few hints that can guide me to the solution. Thanks in advance for your precious help.

Edit: *What I've tried*.

We know that $A^*=\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{B}}(f^*) \sim A^t = (\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{B}}(f))^t \sim A =\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{B}}(f) $.

So, as the characteristic polynomial of $f^*$ is equal to the characteristic polynomial of $f$ I think that the thesis comes straightforward.

If what I said is true, let's add another hypothesis. Let's say that $\psi|_{W}$ is non degenerate. We want to conclude that the characteristic polynomial of $f$ is the product of the characteristic polynomial of $f|_W$ and the characteristic polynomial of $f^*|_{W^{\perp}}$.

What I've tried to say is: If $\psi |_W$ is non degenerate, we have $V= W \oplus W^{\perp}$. But I don't really know how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the direct sum decomposition $V = W \oplus W^{\perp}$ and choose some basis $\beta = (e_1,\dots,e_n)$ such that $(e_1,\dots,e_k)$ is a basis for $W$ and $(e_{k+1},\dots,e_n)$ is a basis for $W^{\perp}$. Since $f(W) \subseteq W$, the matrix representing $f$ with respect to $\beta$ will be block upper triangular

$$ \mathcal{M}_{\beta}(f) = \begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ 0 & C \end{pmatrix} $$

where $A \in M_k(\mathbb{R})$ is the matrix representing $f|_{W}$ with respect to the basis $\beta' = (e_1,\dots,e_k)$ of $W$.  Hence,

$$ \chi_f(\lambda) = \det(A - \lambda I_k) \det(C - \lambda I_{n-k}) = \chi_{f|_{W}}(\lambda) \det(C - \lambda I_{n-k}). $$

Let $G$ be the matrix representing $\psi$ with respect to $\beta$ (so $G_{ij} = \psi(e_i,e_j)$). Because of the direct sum decomposition, the matrix $G$ is block diagonal so write

$$ G = \begin{pmatrix} G_1 & 0 \\ 0 & G_2 \end{pmatrix}. $$

Then

$$ \mathcal{M}_{\beta}(f^{*}) = G^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ 0 & C \end{pmatrix}^t G = \begin{pmatrix} G_1^{-1} & 0 \\ 0 & G_2^{-1} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} A^t & 0 \\ B^t & C^t \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} G_1 & 0 \\ 0 & G_2 \end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix} G_1^{-1} & 0 \\ 0 & G_2^{-1} \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} A^t G_1 & 0 \\ B^t G_1 & C^t G_2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} G_1^{-1} A G_1 & 0 \\ G_2^{-1} B^t G_1 & G_2^{-1} C^t G_2\end{pmatrix} $$

and we immediately see that $W^{\perp}$ is $f^{*}$-invariant and $f|_{W^{\perp}}$ is represented with respect to the basis $\beta'' =
 (e_{k+1},\dots,e_n)$ of $W^{\perp}$ by $G_2^{-1} C^t G_2$ so
$$\chi_{f^{*}|_{W^{\perp}}}(\lambda) = \det(G_2^{-1} C^t G_2 - \lambda I_{n-k}) = \det(G_2^{-1} (C - \lambda I_{n-k})^t G_2) = \det(C - \lambda I_{n-k}). $$

Hence, we get $\chi_f(\lambda) = \chi_{f|_{W}}(\lambda) \chi_{f^{*}|_{W^{\perp}}}(\lambda)$.

Comment: Sorry man, I don't understand a thing: I was told that you can say you have an orthonormal basis if and only if the scalar product is positive definite. In this case, you don't know it, you just know that it is non degenerate. So I think that you can't say $A^*=A^t$ but just $A^* \sim A^t $ which clearly is enough to have the thesis. Tell me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @AlbertoAndrenucci: Sorry if I confused you but I never heard the term "scalar product" applied to a symmetric bilinear pairing which is not positive definite... I've edited my answer so that it works in general.

Comment: I think it's just a question of notation, we use to say "scalar product" to describe a symmetrical bilinear form. If it is positive definite, we say it! Thank you for your answer.